# what is the equivalent of element.style.pixelLeft in Chrome or in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am trying to make my website work in chrome. what should I replace  `menu.style.pixelLeft`  to make it work in Chrome. 
Please suggest.

Comment: Is `menu.style.left` not working?

Comment: To be honest, there is not strict equivalent. Your options are either to use `offsetLeft` or use `style.left` or both. pixelLeft is a mix of both; Depending of what you're trying to achieve, but you won't get exactly the same feature.